# send email through stdin on Debian: "Mailing to remote domains not supported"

Tags: email, smtp, debian

As per [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2477883/1122270), if you want to send mail directly from `stdin`, you can pipe it to `sendmail -t`, as in, `printf "Subject: test\nTo: test@example.org\nFrom: test@example.com\n\ntesting" | sendmail -t`.

However, when I've tried doing this on my Debian 7 (wheezy), I got nothing outside the box, and, from within, `Mailing to remote domains not supported`, from Exim4.  Suggested approach includes running `dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config`, however, there is not a single option to enable sending mail directly through SMTP, without also receiving it.

What's the easiest way to fix Exim4, or quickly replace it with something that's not nearly as complicated?!  I don't even need pool support, just a single attempt to send over SMTP.

Comment: So far, the easiest solution appears to be installing https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/msmtp (as https://packages.debian.org/jessie/dma is not avail in wheezy), but you'd have to manually specify HOST and ENVELOPE-FROM on the command line, which it can't determine from stdin. :/  Any better solution?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> # fgrep remote /var/log/exim4/mainlog.1 | sed -E 's#([ <])[^ <]+@[^ >]+([ >])#\1a@b\2#g' | head -1
> 2019-01-08 00:47:00 1ggebk-00055M-St ** a@b <a@b> R=nonlocal: Mailing to remote domains not supported
> #
> ```

Apart from installing `dma` as per https://packages.debian.org/jessie/dma, which is unavailable in `wheezy`, the solution for `wheezy` appears to be selecting the `internet` option within `dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config`, which, provided the other defaults are kept, doesn't actually open the SMTP port to the internet, because by default it'll only listen on the localhost IPv4/IPv6 addresses.

---

It appears that there's a Debian-specific `/etc/exim4/update-exim4.conf.conf` (yes, it's a double `.conf.conf`, that's not a typo), which plays a part in this fiasco.  Here's the relevant parts after running `dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config` and only changing the first option within the wizard, which enables sending mail, but appears to still keep the SMTP port open only to the machine itself (a default option if you just click-through in the reconfig):

```
dc_eximconfig_configtype='internet'
…
dc_local_interfaces='127.0.0.1 ; ::1'
```