# Create an E-Mail and view it before sending

Tags: java, email, outlook

I'm searching the web for days now and didn't find any solution. Also there is no solution in my other question about OLE.

Is it possible, to create an E-Mail for Outlook, fill in stuff (body, subject) and show it for the user to view so he can click send hisself?

If it is possible, how. What APIs/Frameworks or Libraries are ther which support this. And ist der an SSCCE to view?

I can't get SWT (eclipse) to work. Not with the newest version, it always shows an error. I use x64 and Outlook 2013. To view my error watch here: [How to create an E-Mail in Outlook and make it visible for the User](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18057759/how-to-create-an-e-mail-in-outlook-and-make-it-visible-for-the-user)

I hope somebody knows how this could be done, or just give me the answer it's not possible, so I can stop searching.

Thank you.

**Edit**

I have to use Outlook, because it's the E-Mail Tool used in my company. And I don't want to send it automatically but the user needs to view the E-Mail and send it manually.

Comment: So you want basically send a mail? But why u want to use outlook for it? There is a JavaMail class wich you can use. To actully send the mail you could use the google smtp(if that was your problem with earlier mail programs with java). The mail content you could view in a textbox on a JFrame.

Comment: In java or general? I know that is possible in vba excel to prepare an email with stuff waiting for manual sending

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14869441/read-msg-file-with-java-mail-api-pls-suggest-me/14873139#14873139

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Email is just a text. Sometimes it is formatted as a simple HTML page. So, you can use any HTML viewer to view email content. If you are working on desktop application note that Swing components support simple HTML (version 1.0 or so). If you are working on web based application you can show email text into `div`, `iframe` etc.

If you want to call default email client from your java application use `Desktop.mail(URI)`. Take a look on this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17373/how-do-i-open-the-default-mail-program-with-a-subject-and-body-in-a-cross-platfo).

BTW is seems we are using different google. I typed "call email client from java app" and immediately found the mentioned SO discussion.

**EDIT**

I think that your question was not exactly correct. Outlook is just one of various email clients. Well, very popular. But still one of... It is not guaranteed that it is installed on user's machine. So, you cannot require from **java** application to run **Outlook**. However you can run default email client.

Comment: I can require, because the program i write is designated to me and two collegues. And in our company Outlook is the must have E-Mail tool so I know it's installed. And the program has to have the dependency to use Outlook